# How can I use XPath to find the minimum/maximum value of an attribute for chooses group in a set of elements?

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

```
<foo>
  <bar id="1" score="100" group="beginner" />
  <bar id="2" score="200" group="beginner" />
  <bar id="3" score="300" group="expert" />
  ...
</foo>
```

I try use like this, but something wrong (xpath 1.0)

```
foo/bar[@group='beginner' and not(@score<= preceding-sibling::bar/@score) and not(@score<=following-sibling::bar/@score)]
```

Comment: which xpath version?

Comment: Using xpath 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **xpath 1.0**

```
/foo/bar[@group='beginner'][(not(preceding-sibling::bar[@group='beginner']/@score >= @score) and not(following-sibling::bar[@group='beginner']/@score > @score))      or (not(preceding-sibling::bar[@group='beginner']/@score <= @score) and not(following-sibling::bar[@group='beginner']/@score < @score))]/@score
```

Comment: I not see group filter

Comment: I think need remove [@group='beginner'] and to do two different samples for max and min value separate and it will be good answer. It work. Thanks.

Comment: well,xslt 1.0 dont' have these grouping functions. so lot of effort on getting in between values.

Comment: just check again [@group='beginner'] required!